# Looking For An Auctioneer Yak

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've seen yaks that have a vendor on one side and an auctioneer on the other side...he looks like a genie. Which mount is this, where can it be purchased, and how much does it cost?

Comment: If you can get a screenshot of what you're talking about so we can be sure that we get the answer right, that would help out a lot

Comment: If I happen to see another one, I will.  :-)

Comment: Usually I see them outside the bank at Stormwind.

Answer (score 8):

The only mount with an auctioneer on it is the [Mighty Caravan Brutosaur](https://www.wowhead.com/item=163042/reins-of-the-mighty-caravan-brutosaur) which costs 5,000,000 gold.

What you saw was probably the [Grand Expedition Yak](https://www.wowhead.com/item=84101/reins-of-the-grand-expedition-yak), which has a vendor/blacksmith and a transmogrifier. However, it only costs 120,000 gold.

The other option is the [Traveler's Tundra Mammoth](https://www.wowhead.com/item=44235/reins-of-the-travelers-tundra-mammoth), which has a vendor and a blacksmith, but only costs 20,000 gold.

Comment: No, I have the Grand Expedition Yak.  This had an auctioneer on one side, and it wasn't the brontosaurus.

Comment: Unless they've added something new really recently, I don't think there *is* another mount with an auctioneer on it...

Comment: There is currently no mount, other than the Brutosaur, which has an auctioneer on them. There is no mount like this in PTR, or even in any announced updates (that we know of). Therefore, you are unfortunately mistaken, and it was either a Yak with a different type of vendor, or the Brutosaur. You can view all current mounts in-game (and PTR) [here](https://ptr.wowhead.com/ground-mount-items#0-2-3+18). If it is not listed here, I seriously doubt it is in-game at all, let alone owned by any player.

Comment: The Yak definitely has no auctioneer on it. It has a vendor for selling junk and repairing and a transmog guy.

Comment: Also, while there are toys or consumables that will permit you to change your appearance, the appearance of your pet, or the appearance of your mount, there is no toy which will permit you to change either the merchants your mounts produce or the appearance of a merchant-bearing mount into a similar mount of a different species.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened.  One of the Traveler's Tundra Mammoths was standing right beside the Mighty Caravan Brutosaur.  When I moused over the genie vendor, it showed up as an auctioneer because the two of them were melded together in the same space.  Ah well, I'd hoped.  Thanks for the replies, everyone!

Comment: While we're on this topic, Blizzard is no longer going to sell the Brutosaur in game once Shadowlands comes out.  If you want a mount with an auctioneer on it, I suggest you get it soon.

Comment: Okay, that's just wrong.  They should never discontinue something.  There's absolutely no reason for it, since it takes more effort to remove something that already exists.